# How to display the count of the letter?

Tags: python

I'm working on a dictionary program:

```
strEntry = str(input("Enter a string: ").upper())
strEntry = strEntry.replace(",", "")
strEntry = strEntry.replace(" ", "")

print('')

def freq_finder(strFinder):
  dict = {}
  for i in strFinder:
    keys = dict.keys()
    if i in keys:
      dict[i] += 1
    else:
      dict[i] = 1
  return dict

newDic = freq_finder(strEntry)

print(newDic)

newLetter = str(input("Choose a letter: ").upper())

if newLetter in newDic:
  
  print("Frequency count of that letter:", count(newLetter))
  newDic.pop(newLetter)
  print("Dictinary after that letter removed:", newDic)
else:
  print("Letter not in dictionary")

sortedDic = sorted(newDic)
print(sortedDic)
```

Everything works fine until this part:

```
print("Frequency count of that letter:", count(newLetter))
```

I'm trying to figure out how to display the frequency count of the letter. For example, in the code below, 'S' has a value of 4. So frequency count of the letter 'S' would be 4. What should I do to get this result?

It should look something like this:

```
Enter a string: Magee, Mississippi

Dictionary:  {'M': 2, 'A': 1, 'G': 1, 'E': 2, 'I': 4, 'S': 4, 'P': 2}
Choose a letter: S
**Frequency count of that letter: 4**
Dictionary after that letter removed:  {'M': 2, 'A': 1, 'G': 1, 'E': 2, 'I': 4, 'P': 2}
Letters sorted: ['A', 'E', 'G', 'I', 'M', 'P']
```

I would highly appreciate it if you could tell me what's wrong and how to fix it.

Comment: Just replace `count(newLetter)` with `newDic[newLetter]`

Comment: @Lagerbaer It does work. Thanks, but could you please explain to me how it works?

Comment: Please don't overwrite Python builtins such as `dict` unless you really know what you're doing. This will cause issues down the road.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the value from the dictionary all you have to do is this.

```
print("Frequency count of that letter:", newDic[newLetter])
```

Comment: It does work. Thanks, but could you please explain to me how it works?

Comment: Well this is how you access the elements of a dictionary.

Comment: Given a dictionary `sample = {'a':1 ,'b':'2, 'c':3}`,  if I want to access the value corresponding to key 'b', all I have to do is `sample['b']`. This is how an element in a dictionary is accessed. Similarly in your question, `newDic` is the dictionary and `newLetter` is the key.

Answer (score 0):

you seen to have forgotten to define the count function

just add this in your code and it should work

```py
def count(e):
  return newDic[e]
```

```py
strEntry = str(input("Enter a string: ").upper())
strEntry = strEntry.replace(",", "")
strEntry = strEntry.replace(" ", "")

print('')

def freq_finder(strFinder):
  dict = {}
  for i in strFinder:
    keys = dict.keys()
    if i in keys:
      dict[i] += 1
    else:
      dict[i] = 1
  return dict

newDic = freq_finder(strEntry)

print(newDic)

newLetter = str(input("Choose a letter: ").upper())

def count(e):
  return newDic[e]

if newLetter in newDic:
  
  print("Frequency count of that letter:", count(newLetter))
  newDic.pop(newLetter)
  print("Dictinary after that letter removed:", newDic)
else:
  print("Letter not in dictionary")

sortedDic = sorted(newDic)
print(sortedDic)
```